# Unity has a documentation problem about Time.fixedDeltaTime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity’s Time.fixedDeltaTime documentation it states that "**Unity does not adjust fixedDeltaTime based on Time.timeScale**." But in Unity’s Time.fixedUnscaleDeltaTime documentation it states  that "**Unlike Time.fixedDeltaTime this value is not affected by Time.timeScale.**" What is going on?

[fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity.cn/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

[fixedUnscaledDeltaTime](https://docs.unity.cn/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-fixedUnscaledDeltaTime.html)

According to actual operation, fixedDeltaTime is indeed not affected by Time.timeScale. So is this a mistake in the documentation of Time.fixedUnscaleDeltaTime or is my understanding inaccurate and problematic?

Comment: Any link to Time.fixedUnscaleDeltaTime documentation? It's first time I hear of it, and can't find anything about it

Comment: @MG https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-fixedUnscaledDeltaTime.html

Comment: In fixedDeltaTime  documentation: "Unity does not adjust fixedDeltaTime based on Time.timeScale. The fixedDeltaTime interval is always relative to the in-game time which Time.timeScale affects."

Which means Time.timesScale does affect Time.timeScale. The first sentence means that it's not adjusted to normal time based on Time.timeScale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sentence is indeed confusing, and thanks for pointing it out!
The documentation is correct but could be elaborated.

`Time.timeScale` controls the overall time scale of the game. It can be used to slow down or speed up **the passage of time** in the game.

`Time.fixedUnscaleDeltaTime` will occur in intervals based on the real-time passage (independent of `Time.timeScale`)

When you change `Time.timeScale`, the perceived speed of time in the game is affected. However, while **the value** of `fixedDeltaTime` remains the same (unaffected), **the number of times it occurs per second** (interval) can change based on `Time.timeScale`.